# How can i unit test console input in scala?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

How can i unit test console input in scala with scalaTest.
Code under Test:

```
object ConsoleAction {
  def readInput(in: InputStream): List[String] = {
    val bs = new BufferedSource(in)(Codec.default)
    val l = bs.getLines()
    l.takeWhile(_!="").toList
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val l = ConsoleAction.readInput(System.in)
    println("--> "+l)
  }
}
```

I'd like to test the readInput method.
A one line input can be tested like that:

```
"Result list" should "has 1 element" in {
  val input = "Hello\\n"
  val is = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
  assert(ConsoleAction.readInput(is).size===1)
}
```

... but what is the way for multiline input?

```
input line 1
input line 2
```

thx

Comment: Uhm... what is the problem with having multiple lines in `input` variable? e.g. `val input = "foo\nbar\n"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies with how you're escaping your newline.  You're doing "\\n" rather than "\n".   This test should pass.

```
"Result list" should "has 2 elements" in {
  val input = "Hello\nWorld\n"
  val is = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
  assert(ConsoleAction.readInput(is).size===2)
}
```